# Augment all the images in a folder in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I am trying to augment all the satellite image(.TIFF format) at once but keep running into an error
Error: **"('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (0,))"**
When i do it one at a time there is no error but when i run it in a folder it gives me the error.Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong

Thanks

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from skimage import io
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=45,     
        width_shift_range=0.2,   
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='constant', cval=125)

image_directory = 'E:\\opencv'
SIZE = 150
dataset = []

my_images = os.listdir(image_directory)
for i, image_name in enumerate(my_images):
    if (image_name.split('.')[1] == 'TIFF'):
        image = io.imread(image_directory + image_name)
        image = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
        image = image.resize((SIZE,SIZE))
        dataset.append(np.array(image))

x = np.array(dataset)
i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=16,  
                          save_to_dir='E:\\opencv', 
                          save_prefix='a', 
                          save_format='TIFF'):
    i += 1
    if i > 20:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

modify code as follows

```
for i, image_name in enumerate(my_images):
    if (image_name.split('.')[1] == 'TIFF'):
        fpath=os.path.join(image_directory, image_name)
        print (fpath) # if this does not execute your if statement is incorrect
        image = io.imread(fpath)
        print (image.shape) # verify the image was read correctly
        image = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
        image = image.resize((SIZE,SIZE))
        print (image.size) # verify image was resized
        dataset.append(np.array(image))
```

or

```
for i, image_name in enumerate(my_images):
    if (image_name.split('.')[1] == 'TIFF'):        
        image = io.imread(image_directory + '/' + image_name)
        image = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
        image = image.resize((SIZE,SIZE))
        dataset.append(np.array(image))
```